# Install Oracle 11g completely by PuTTY command line

Tags: shell, ssh, oracle11g, putty, remote-server

How can I successfully download and install Oracle 11g database into server machine which I have access only to Command Line Interface via PuTTY? What is the best way to do this?

P.S: X11 forwarding is not working for me

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Oracle in **silent mode** on command line using response files.

> Silent mode
>
> If you include responses for all of the prompts in the response file
>   and specify the -silent option when starting Oracle Universal
>   Installer, then Oracle Universal Installer runs in silent mode. During
>   a silent-mode installation, Oracle Universal Installer does not
>   display any screens. Instead, it displays progress information in the
>   terminal that you used to start it.

Oracle has officially document this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32002/app_nonint.htm#LADBI415).